# How to decouple trac from, or align trac with, apache authorization

Tags: apache, authorization, trac

I've had a trac server running for about a year now - chugging along just as expected. Today, I implemented basic authorization on the apache server that trac runs under.

Trac now picks up the user as authenticated by Apache, and doesn't allow either logout or a login.

I tried to create an apache user with the same name and password as a trac user, but the behavior remained - I can't access trac.

How do I align trac with Apache authorization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to point trac to the htpasswd file for Apache users and then set permissions to access the login page through Apache. You can find more information [here](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracCgi).

Answer (score 2):

One of the drawbacks of HttpAuth is the inability to log out (short of closing your browser, or clearing browser auth).  You probably want to grab [AccountManagerPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AccountManagerPlugin) from [trac-hacks.org](http://trac-hacks.org) and set it up with the form-based login.  That gives you the ability to log out.